# How to use urlopen of urllib to save files when login is required?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, urlopen

I used the following Python codes to download files. The codes work when no login and password are required. The target file will be saved in the name of `theFile`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
pageUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt"
savePath="C:/Users/HMC/Desktop/theFile"
html = urlopen(pageUrl)
html_b = urlopen(pageUrl).read()
savefile(savePath, html_b)
```

However, for some specific website, login and password are required. I take `www.fki.inf.unibe.ch` as an example, I already have a username `myaccount012` and password `mypw012` (They works. You can try the login/password to access the file in the browser).

So I changed `pageUrl` as below:

```
pageUrl = "http://myaccount012:mypw012@www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png"
```

However, when I run the code, I have the error message as below:-

```
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'mypw012@www.fki.inf.unibe.ch'
```

How can I get it fixed? Many thanks!

Comment: Probably you should just use `requests` instead of urllib. Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an example for HTTP Basic Authentication:

```
import urllib.request
# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
                          uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
                          user='klem',
                          passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

So you need to add a HTTPBasicAuthHandler and install your own opener with the right password/username.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried your codes and used `realm='PDQ Application', uri='www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png', user='myaccount012',passwd='mypw012'`, and run `urllib.request.urlopen('www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png')`, but I got `ValueError: unknown url type: 'www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png'`, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The error says it. 'www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs....' isn't an URL. It is a hostname with some path attached. An URL starts with a scheme like http://, https://, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I added the `http://` and used `realm='PDQ Application', uri='http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png', user='myaccount012',passwd='mypw012'`, and run `urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/DBs/iamDB/data/forms/a01-000u.png')`, but I got `HTTPError: Unauthorized`. The user name and password should be okay, and the file is accessible in browser by using this user name and password.